# Pass the values, without sending as parameters in the function

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I pass the values `userId`, `sessionId`,  `cb`, without sending as a parameter in the function?

```js
userSessionInfo: function (userId, sessionId, cb) {
  if (!sessionId || sessionId == '') {
    let user_id = userId;
```

I need to do something like:

```js
userSessionInfo: function () {
  userId = "..."; 
  sessionId = "..."; 
  cb = "...";
```

Is possible?

Comment: Make the parameters global , or part of a context.

Comment: Use `let` or `const` to declare these variables before using them (the same way you did with `user_id`) - if that's your goal. As for making them global/contextual, well, that actually makes the function less useful (as it'll only be usable in a proper context).

Comment: Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a function without passing any parameters, you could wrap that function in a class and treat it like a method.

```js
class UserSession {
  constructor(userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.sessionId = null;
    this.cb = null;
  }
  info() {
    if (!this.sessionId || this.sessionId == '') {
      let user_id = this.userId;
      return user_id;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const userSession = new UserSession(1001);

console.log(userSession.info()); // 1001
```

Comment: Polyshirl, thanks very much for help.
Its work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, but if what you want is for some dynamic values to be defined inside the function, you can take advantage of `closures`:

From MDN:

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

Here is an example based on the code you gave us that shows how you can take advantage of closures:

```js
const userSession = (function(){
  const userId    = 1
  const sessionId = 2 
  const cb        = 3

  return function() {
    console.log(userId, sessionId, cb)
  }
})()

console.log(userSession())
// 1 2 3
```

Every variable available on the scope of the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) will be accessible by the function being return. All this data will travel with the `userSession` function.

[IIFE Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: thanks for help, but I follow other solution.
Thanks man. ;)